# Прошу помочь, делаю простой калькулятор, но возникло 2 проблемы.

Tags: java, android

Прошу помочь, делаю простой калькулятор как первую программу, но когда я стираю последнюю цифру программа вылетает и также я не смог сделать так чтобы в edit text добавить запятую, при нажатии на запятую на цифровой клавиатуре - программа вылетает.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button plus;
    private Button minus;
    private Button umnogenie;
    private Button delenie;
    private TextView text1;
    private EditText vvod1;
    private EditText vvod2;
    private  double a,b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        minus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        delenie= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        umnogenie= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        vvod1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        vvod2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        delenie.setOnClickListener(this);
        umnogenie.setOnClickListener(this);

        vvod1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }



            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s == null)
                    a= 0;
                else
                    a = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        vvod2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s == null)
                    b= 0;
                else
                    b = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.button9: text1.setText(String.valueOf(a+b));
                break;
            case R.id.button10: text1.setText(String.valueOf(a-b));
                break;
            case R.id.button11: text1.setText(String.valueOf(a/b));
                break;
            case R.id.button12: text1.setText(String.valueOf(a*b));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Запуская программу в смартфоне я ввожу числа. Если я хочу добавить запятую программа просто выдает ошибку и вылетает, я не знаю как исправить. И другое что, такая же ситуация- я ввожу числа и ввел то что не хотел, стираю, и когда я стер последнюю цифру программа опять выдает ошибку и закрывается

Comment: Либо запустите программу в эмуляторе и тогда ошибку получите в консоли IDE, либо используйте [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) и извлеките ошибку из системного журнала смартфона. Причина вылета написана в ошибке.

Comment: В том то и проблема что код программы работает без ошибок, но я не знаю как добавить или отредактировать эти нюансы

Comment: Обратите внимание на эту и подобную ей строчку: a = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()). Что будет, если ввести запятую?

Comment: Да... Программа вылетит. И тогда вместо int нужно вставить double? Я просто начинающий....

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: А еще кое что. А почему когда я стираю последнюю цифру у меня программа вылетает. Мне надо настроить s?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу ни на одном форуме найти

Comment: сам недавно делал калькулятор, можете посмотреть реализацию https://github.com/boneferz/Calculator . Проверяйте, если стираете последнюю цифру, что бы оставался ноль вместо отсутствия какого либо числа, иначе будет ошибка. Есть у вас какие то еще трудности кроме этого?

Comment: Может стирая последнюю цыфру у Вас остается что-то, что потом не парсится. Например NULL или пустая строка, которые могут и не распарсится?

Answer (score -1):

```
a = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
```

Зачем парсить `int` если у Вас тип `Double`?

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/54-urok-19-pishem-prostoj-kalkuljator.html

Comment: Пример простого калькулятора